# What is the smallest number which can be represented in python?

Tags: python, floating-point

What is the smallest number which can be represented in python?

I have seen as small as `2.05623357236e-296` but can there be any smaller?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out [`sys.float_info`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info)

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info 
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

From the docs

> ```
> min       DBL_MIN      minimum positive normalized float 
> min_exp   DBL_MIN_EXP  minimum integer e such that radix**(e-1) is a normalized float
> ```

On my system it is mentioned as `min=2.2250738585072014e-308`

Answer (score 9):

Check `sys.float_info.min`. Note that this is the minimum *normalized* value; the minimum [denormalized value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) may be smaller but numerical accuracy will suffer.

With usual 64-bit floating-point numbers, the normalized min is approximately `2.2e-308`. The denormalized min can be much less, down to `4.94e-324`:

```
>>> 5e-324
4.9406564584124654e-324
```

---

It is also worth pointing out that the `decimal` module's `Decimal` type can represent *arbitrarily* small numbers, limited only by available memory.